# Auto-complete parameters in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

There is a great auto-complete feature available in Netbeans and Eclipse but lack in IntelliJ, or I just can't find the setting to enable it?

When I typed the code below, Netbeans (1)auto fill the parameters "text1" and "text2", (2)popup a list of variables to modify, and I can also (3)use tab key to switch between those parameters.

While in IntelliJ, not only I have to press hotkey "ctrl+space"(which conflicts with the windows Input Method hotkey) to popup the variable list, but I can't use tab key to switch between parameters.

IntelliJ is a great IDE, this is probably the only thing that really annoys me.

Is there anyway to make IntelliJ works like Netbeans?

[image]

Comment: There is no such feature afaik. You should try Ctrl+Shift+Space instead of Ctrl+Space - this will show you only suitable parameters. Also try Ctrl+P to show all needed parameters.

Comment: As said Ctrl+Shift+Space is probably better. And don't forget that pressing that a second and third time gives you more relevant alternatives.

Comment: A plugin is available for this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76046709/1879731

Answer (score 1):

What has really annoyed me for a long time (especially steps 3 & 4) is that if you want to input something like:

```
toBeCalled("a","b");
```

you have to do the following:

1. "
2. a
3. Right
4. ,
5. "
6. b

The trick I just found is that you can do the following:

1. ,
2. Ctrl+P
3. Use tab/shift+tab key to switch between parameters
4. Input the parameter

This is probably the best way I can think of so far.